# Is a fundamental type volatile initialization an observable behavior?

Tags: c++, initialization, language-lawyer, volatile

Consider this function:

```
void f(void* loc)
  {
  auto p = new(loc) volatile int{42};
  *p = 0;
  }
```

I have check the generated code by *clang, gcc and CL,* none of them elide the initialization. (The answer may be seen by the hardwer:).

Is it an extension provided by compilers to the standard? Does the standard allow compilers not to perform the write 42?

Actualy for objects of class type, it is specfied that constructor of an object is executed without consideration for the `volatile` qualifier [class.ctor]:

> A constructor can be invoked for a const, volatile or const volatile object. const and volatile
>   semantics (10.1.7.1) are not applied on an object under construction. They come into effect when the
>   constructor for the most derived object (4.5) ends.

Comment: Why do you think the initialization should not happen?  To the programmer, keyword 'volatile' is documentation that some other process or equipment might change the value. To the compiler, the word is a command to _not_ optimize away code access (read or write) which it otherwise might do.

Comment: @DOUGLASO.MOEN Because it is stated in the standard that I can be elided for object of class type! T.C. made me discover that few minutes ago, it surprised me.

Comment: This is tricky. The requirement is that ["accesses through volatile glvalues are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine"](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/intro.execution#7.1), where "access" [means](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/defns.access) to "read or modify the value of an object". I'm not seeing a volatile glvalue in the first line, much less an access through one.

Comment: OTOH, C has the requirement that "at every sequence point the value last stored in the object shall agree with that prescribed by the abstract machine, except as modified by the unknown factors mentioned previously"; that certainly seems like saying you can't omit the initialization, but I don't see a corresponding rule in C++.

Comment: Is placement new relevant here? I.e. it's the same problem for:

volatile int x{42};
volatile int *p = &x;
*p = 0;

Comment: @MikhailMaltsev Indeed for the language it makes no difference. So I prefered an exemple describing a may be (depending on the answer) usefull case.

Comment: @MikhailMaltsev I don't think a signal handler can your `x`. A signal handler can know Oliv's `loc` and read the value stored. But the signal handler can never have a chance to fire between two writes and never see the first write!

Answer (score 0):

[intro.execution]/8 lists the minimum requirements for a conforming implementation; these are also known as “observable behavior”. The first requirement is that “Access to volatile objects are evaluated strictly according to the rules of the abstract machine.” The compiler is required to produce all observable behavior. In particular, it is not allowed to remove accesses to volatile objects. And note that “object” here is used in the compiler-writer’s sense: it includes built-in types.

Comment: If you interpret the standard this way, then most common C++ compilers for most common platforms do not comply with the standard. For example, GCC on x86 does not emit a memory barrier between two volatile writes which permits those writes to execute in any order or to be coalesced into a single write. (Personally, I believe this is not a reasonable interpretation of the C++ standard. And it seems compiler writers, at least, agree with me.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz — `volatile` is fundamentally about memory-mapped device registers. If you don’t have guarantees on the occurrence and the order of reads and writes your pacemaker could send your heart rate to 200, your car engine could explode, and you might even launch a nuclear attack against North Korea. Whether or not such requirements are applicable in situations where `volatile` is more-or-less irrelevant doesn’t change those requirements.

Comment: The existence of memory-mapped device registers is platform-specific. I do agree that compiler writers try to make `volatile` useful for that purpose where the platform has such things. But if you think the C++ standard gives you enough to ensure you can sanely talk to a platform-specific device like a pacemaker, you're out of your mind. You need platform-specific support all over the place. Of course, it's a quality-of-implementation issue whether `volatile` provides the platform-specific features you are most likely to need.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz — you’re reading far more into my comments than what I said or intended. Note that “if you don’t have X you can’t do Y” is not the same as “if you have X you can do Y”. And, no, I’m not out of my mind.

Comment: So now you're saying that the standard requires the compiler to provide some of, but not all of, the necessary support to use memory-mapped device registers, even where every bit of what support is or is not necessary is platform-specific? What does it mean, in a platform-neutral way, to "observe" a memory operation?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a coherent question because what it means for a compiler to perform a write is platform-specific. There is no platform-independent notion of performing a write other than perhaps seeing the effects of a write in a subsequent read.

As you see, typical compilers on x86 will emit a write instruction but no memory barrier. The CPU may reorder the write, coalesce it, or even avoid doing any write to main memory because of the way the platform's cache coherence works.

The reason they made this implementation choice is that it makes `volatile` work for a broad range of applications, including those where the standard requires it to work, and because it has acceptable performance consequences. The standard, being platform-neutral, doesn't dictate platform-specific decisions like this and compiler writers do not understand it to do that.

They could have forced every `volatile` access to be uncoalsecable, un-reorderable, and pushed through the cache subsystem to main memory. But that would provide terrible performance and, on this platform, no significant benefits. So they don't do it, and they don't understand the C++ standard to suggest that there's some mythical observer on the memory bus who must see specific things. The very existence of a memory bus is platform-specific. The standard is not platform-specific.

You will sometimes see people argue, for example, that the standard somehow requires the compiler to issue instructions to do `volatile` writes in order but that it doesn't matter if the CPU coalesces or re-orders the writes. This is, frankly, silly. The C++ standard doesn't impose requirements on the instructions compilers generate but rather on what those instructions must actually do when executed. It doesn't distinguish between optimizations done by a CPU and optimizations done by a compiler and any such distinctions would be platform-specific anyway.

If the standard allows a CPU to re-order two writes, then it allows the compiler to re-order them. It does not, and cannot, make that kind of distinction. Of course, compiler writers may still decide that they will issues the writes in order even though the CPU can re-order them because that may make the most sense on their platform.

Comment: I thought that putting "language-lawyer" in the key word list was clear enough.

Comment: Whatsoever it is clearly stated in the standard that volatile does not imply any interthread sequencing. This is not subject here. Neither is the subject what implementation consider an access. The question is realy about what is stated in the c++ standard.

Comment: @Oliv My answer has nothing to do with interthread sequencing. It has to do with the operations taking place in order or not. They don't. Would you prefer I focus more on why the standard doesn't say what folks like Pete Becker think it says?

Comment: @Oliv It's essentially that what it means to "observe" a memory operation is entirely platform-specific. There is no platform-neutral way to "observe" a memory operation other than perhaps with another memory operation. If your question is about what instructions the compiler produces rather than what it makes the platform do, then it's not a question about the C++ standard since the C++ standard makes no distinction.

Comment: OK!! I understand your trouble. "Observable behavior" is a standardized term, which is defined to be whatever an implementation would want. I do not know any implementation which has documentation for what they consider an observable behavior, but your are right, they have decided that the "observer" implicitly mentioned in the expression "observable behavior" is the CPU (which will receive a load or read instruction and do whatever it wants with it), and not the human in front of the computer!

Comment: @Oliv Yes, precisely. Compiler writers must make `volatile` support the specific cases the standard requires (such as `sig_atomic_t`) or their compiler does not comply with the standard. Other than that, they decide what they think is most useful on their platform as a quality of implementation issue. These are necessarily platform specific because there is no platform-independent way to "observe" a memory operation.